# LayoutInflater Unreachable Statement

Tags: android

[image]

I try to create some List Adapter for my listview, but it says the LayoutInflater is uncracheble statement. I already search for similar question but no idea. hope you guys can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: remove return from first line. as you are returning real view at last.

Comment: don't add code as an image

Comment: don't use screenshot for posting code

Comment: ok, my bad. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely, any code after `return` statement is unreachable. Remove your first-line `return` statement.

Comment: @ maghfirzakir Why are you returning two views? Please remove one of the return statements. Either you return super class view or return view which you have inflated.

Comment: ah! I didn't realize, auto generate. thanks!